# Jump back in time in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, branch

I'm new to SVN and I'm quite confused about a problem. I am using Tortoise SVN.

I have rev 8 and later rev 11 of a project. Until 11 it was a straightforward process, but now I have to jump  back to rev 8, which is tagged by the way and countinue from that. I already made a working copy of rev8, and made some changes.

How do I "rewind the tape" of the trunk to rev8, and make a branch of recent trunk, and commit my changes on rev8, so that the result is going to be the trunk?

The docs that came across all write endless pages about branching and tagging - the actual top version in the repository - but not about these operations in past revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
svn merge -r11:8 path/
```

Will 'revert' all changes made from 8 to 11.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's branch the most recent change. I like using full URLs for branching:

```
$ svn cp svn://localhost/trunk svn://localhost/branches/foo  #Creating branch foo
```

Now, we can remove changes 9 onward:

```
$ svn merge -rHEAD:8 .
```

Notice I didn't have to specify the tag you used for revision 8. That's because revision numbers are pretty good at acting as tags. I normally only tag interesting revisions -- revisions that are going outside of development, or a revision that I believe might be important for some reason later on.

By the way. I could have done things in reverse order too:

```
$ svn merge -r11:8 .   #Remove changes 9 through 11
$ svn commit -m "Removing yucky stuff"   #Creates revision #12
```

Oops! I should have branched revision 11! Let's do it now:

```
$ svn copy -r11 . svn://localhost/branches/foo   #Revision #11 is now branch "foo"
```

And if you prefer full URLS:

```
$ svn copy -r11 svn://localhost/trunk@11 svn://localhost/branches/foo
```

Comment: A better / more full explanation indeed. However, you could avoid that first `svn merge` by just a `svn cp svn:/source/etc@8 svn://target/etc`, even less work ;)

Comment: @Wrikken That would be great if revision 8 could be on the branch and revision 11 remains on the trunk. However, the OP wanted version 8 on the trunk and version 11 on a branch. I guess he could `svn mv` trunk to a branch, and then do a `svn cp` from revision 8 into trunk. That would also work, but might cause problems with users who have trunk checked out.

Comment: Yeah, i missed the part about the `cp` being on the server, but the `merge` being on the current checkout, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

1. check out head revision
2. open log
3. right click on the revision you want to become the new head
4. click "revert to this revision"
5. commit

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout trunk.
2. In a different directory export r8 (svn export).  That way the ".svn" meta-directories are avoided.
3. Copy all the r8 files into trunk.
4. Commit.

(5. If trunk had additional files that weren't in r8, you'll need to "svn remove" those manually).

As you can probably surmise this is not really "rewinding back the tape."   Instead the tape keeps going forward, but r12 will coincidentally look exactly like r8 if you do it this way.  :-)

Comment: ps.  Your question suggests a slightly more complicated situation (e.g., seems you want to also start a new branch based on r11?).  If that's the case, I can improve my answer, but for now I'm assuming the simpler scenario:  that you just want to go back in time.

Answer (score 0):

To create a branch from a given revision, just choose "merge/branch..." and then check the radio button "specific revision in repository" and enter the revision number (11)

To get the the trunk back to how it was in revision 8, choose "Show log...", then select the revision you want to rollback to (8), right-click, and then choose "revert to this revision". Then commit. This will create an additional revision (13) which will be identical to revision 8.

Make sure not to merge the revision 13 into the branch you created from revisoon 11, since it would also rollback the changes in the branch. To make sure it doesn't happen, merge revision 13 from trunk into the branch, but select the checkbox "only record the merge" (IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

Here a different information, therefore an answer (but the answers of @David_W, @maxim1000 and  @Wrikken help to do the job).

What a lot of people stumble upon is that Subversion only allows to working on the head of each branch. That is not a but, but a feature. It is therefore not possible to rewrite history, and you are safe that no one will change history.

That is the reason, why you have to do the (abstracted) steps:

1. Checkout a current version locally.
2. Do a reverse patch (that means r8 to r11 in the reverse order) on your local copy.
3. Commit these changes, so that the new content of your working copy (that is exactly the same as revision 8) will go onto the HEAD.